# Why doesn't Gulp work in Foundation for Emails framework?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, foundation, npm-start

I install [Foundation for Emails](https://get.foundation/emails/docs/sass-guide.html) according to the instructions
and go into the project folder by `cd F:\mailing\modules`.

The npm packages didn't install for some reason.

Ok, now I'm installing them by myself `npm i`.
I start the server and this is what happens:

```
PS F:\mailing\modules> npm start

> foundation-emails-template@2.4.0 start
> gulp

[16:13:17] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[16:13:17] Error: Cannot find module '@babel/register' from 'F:\mailing\modules'
[16:13:17] Failed to load external module babel-register
[16:13:17] Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register' from 'F:\mailing\modules'
[16:13:17] Failed to load external module babel-core/register
[16:13:17] Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core/register' from 'F:\mailing\modules'
[16:13:17] Failed to load external module babel/register
[16:13:17] Error: Cannot find module 'babel/register' from 'F:\mailing\modules'
[16:13:17] Local gulp not found in F:\mailing\modules
[16:13:17] Try running: npm install gulp
```

Ok, I install gulp locally and run it:

```
PS F:\mailing\modules> npm start

> foundation-emails-template@2.4.0 start
> gulp

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\mailing\modules\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

Then I install gulp globally – same sh*t.

WTHF?